# How do I add a SVG element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a simple HTML document that contains a SVG image.  I want to add an element to the SVG image using Javascript.  So I went about it the same way you would add any HTML element in Javascript; use `createElement()` to create the element, and then use `appendChild()` to add it to the tree.  Below is my attempt; in this case, I am trying to add a blue circle when the user clicks on the document.

```js
document.body.onclick = function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    var circle = document.createElement("circle");
    document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(circle);
    circle.setAttribute("cx", 50);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", 50);
    circle.setAttribute("r", 50);
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "blue");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg id="svg" width="100" height="100"></svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the example, the circle doesn't show up when you click.  I can see that the event is occurring, because it prints a line to the console on every click.  If I take a look at the page source (after I click once), the HTML tree looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg id="svg" width="100" height="100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="blue"></circle>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, if I just hardcode it like that, the circle shows up just fine.  So, what is the difference between my first and second example?  Why does the circle show up in the second example, but not the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To append SVG element you must use `createElementNS` with namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` instead `createElement`.

```js
document.body.onclick = function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(circle);
    circle.setAttribute("cx", 50);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", 50);
    circle.setAttribute("r", 50);
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "blue");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg id="svg" width="100" height="100"></svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a proper namespace:

```
 (xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"></svg>
```

use document.createElementNS for svg elements like circle, rectangle

Also, if you are using a framework like Angular, you might need to sanitize your SVG.